# Conflict libraries lodash.js and underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

My project uses the lodash.js library. Off I need to add my project to another project that uses the underscore.js library.
This puts me in conflict errors between these two libraries.

I tried writing this, but it does not change anything:

```
<script src="/web/externals/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="/web/externals/lodash/lodash.js"></script>

<script>
    window.lodash = _.noConflict();
    window.underscore = _.noConflict();
</script>

<app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
```

//////////EDIT////////

```
<script src="/web/externals/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="/web/externals/lodash/lodash.js"></script>

<script>
    var lodash = _.noConflict()
</script>

<app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: I may be wrong but idt lodash exports `_` anymore, have you tried just referencing it as `lodash`? what exactly is the error you're seeing?

Comment: You might want to think about switching your project to use underscore. Having two similar competing libraries isn't good for performance/efficiency.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak
Yes I tried .. 
I have this error : '"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined"' at 'lodash.js'

Comment: try just `var lodash = _.noConflict()`, then `_` should be underscore and `lodash` will reference lodash

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak
I edited my post. I have to do like this ? 
I'm not sure I understood what you're telling me.

Comment: @Floriane yeah that's what I mean, did it work? What `.noConflict` does is return a reference to lodash so you need to store it in a variable. It still might not work though, this is a pretty weird issue. I agree with @andy that you should just use one or the other

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak
Ok but where do I have to call the variable 'lodash'?
No for the moment it does not change anything..

Comment: well now `lodash` is equivalent to `_` so instead of for example saying `_.each()` you say `lodash.each()` that is the purpose of `.noConflict()`. Before you call `.noConflict()` log the value of `_` e.g. `console.log(_)`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that still does not wok .. It puts the same error than before.

Comment: Before you call `.noConflict()` log the value of `_` e.g. `console.log(_)`  do that and share with me what it says

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak
I have this : `ƒ (n){return n instanceof j?n:this instanceof j?(this._wrapped=n,void 0):new j(n)}`

Answer (score 1):

To use `noConflicts` in this case, you need to import one library, use `_.noConflicts`, then import the other.  For example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
<script>
    window.lodash = _.noConflict();
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.underscore = _.noConflict()
</script>
  

<script>
    console.log("Lodash version is " + lodash.VERSION)
    console.log("Underscore version is " + underscore.VERSION) 
</script>
```

---

FWIW, though, it might be worth looking into bundling your apps with something like `webpack`.  That would allow each to have its own version of dependencies, without needing to fight over the global scope.

Comment: I've tested it, and it does work.  I've replaced my example code with a snippet, so you can see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call noConflict once, and you don't need to alter the window object either (though you can it is completely unnecessary). Copy the below code, put it in an HTML file, load it in your favorite browser and check the console. You will see it works without any conflicts

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var __ = _.noConflict();
</script>

<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script>
  var string = 'test';
  var array = ['1', '2', '3'];

  //starts with is a lodash function
  console.log(__.startsWith(string, 't'));

  //shuffle is an underscore function
  console.log(_.shuffle(array));
</script>
```

You can name the lodash variable whatever you want, and keep underscore as _

If you'd rather keep lodash as _ and rename underscore just swap the load order of the 2 scripts

```
 <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script>
    var __ = _.noConflict();
</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var string = 'test';
  var array = ['1', '2', '3'];

  console.log(_.startsWith(string, 't'));
  console.log(__.shuffle(array));
</script>
```

If this doesn't work for you then there is something else wrong and you need to post more code.

Comment: It does not work .. I have the same error than before. 
I didn't understant why because when I try your solution, the two console.log return the good answer `lodash_fct : true
underscore_fct : (3) ["3", "1", "2"]`